notifee/react-native onForegroundEvent doesn't work with React-native 0.74.5 ( sdk target 34)
my mobile app uses notifee library to display and manipulate notifications, and it works fine with targetSdkVersion 33. however when I upgrade to 34, the onForegroundEvent event is no longer working (everything else works fine). like the code below console.log(
[onForegroundEvent] notification id: ${notification?.id}, event type: ${EventType[type]}${pressActionLabel},
); not shown). Help me please
"react-native": "0.71.17",
"@notifee/react-native": "^7.7.0",

buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"

import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Button, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import notifee, {
  EventType,
  AuthorizationStatus,
  AndroidImportance,
  AndroidVisibility,
} from '@notifee/react-native';
import BootSplash from 'react-native-bootsplash';

function App() {
  const requestUserPermission = async () => {
    const settings = await notifee.requestPermission();
    await BootSplash.hide({fade: true});

    if (settings.authorizationStatus >= AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED) {
      console.log('Permission settings:', settings);
    } else {
      console.log('User declined permissions');
    }
  };
  const checkChannelPermission = async () => {
    const channel = await notifee.getChannel('default');

    if (channel?.blocked) {
      console.log('Channel is disabled');
    } else {
      console.log('Channel is enabled:', channel);
    }
  };

  // Subscribe to events
  useEffect(() => {
    checkChannelPermission();
    return notifee.onForegroundEvent(async ({type, detail}) => {
      const {notification, pressAction} = detail;
      const pressActionLabel = pressAction
        ? `, press action: ${pressAction?.id}`
        : '';
      console.log(
        `[onForegroundEvent] notification id: ${notification?.id},  event type: ${EventType[type]}${pressActionLabel}`,
      );
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await requestUserPermission();
    })();
  }, []);

  const notification = {
    title: 'Basic',
    body: 'notification',
    android: {
      channelId: 'default',
      pressAction: {
        id: 'default',
      },
    },
    ios: {
      sound: 'default',
    },
  };

  const onDisplayNotificationPress = async () => {
    await notifee.deleteChannel(notification.android?.channelId || 'default');
    console.log('changelId:', notification.android?.channelId);
    // Create a channel
    await notifee.createChannel({
      id: notification.android?.channelId || 'default',
      name: notification.android?.channelId || 'default',
      importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
    });

    try {
      await notifee.displayNotification(notification);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <View style={styles.contentItem}>
            <View style={styles.contentItemText}>
              <Text>{`Notification: ${notification.title}`}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={[styles.button]}>
              <Button
                color={(Platform.OS === 'ios' && '#fff') || '#44337A'}
                title={'Display Notification'}
                onPress={onDisplayNotificationPress}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;

